# Redirecionar usuário para páginas requisitadas após login

Tags: java, jsf, login

Aqui na empresa é comum passarem links de noticias do portal para outros via email, porém quando o usuário abre o link ele pede autenticação no sistema, mas após fazer o login ele é redirecionado para a página inicial (index.jsf) e não para a noticia que ele queria acessar.

[image: método de login]

[image: phaseListener método beforePhase]

[image: Front-end com form de login]

Comment: Isso acontece porque o `shiro` está configurado, para sempre que algum usuário realize o login, seja redirecionado para a página `index.jsf`. Você precisa de um tratamento que capture a URL que será acessada e armazene isso até que o usuário se autentique. Uma ideia (não creio que seja a mais correta) seria que você passasse essa URL para o próprio bean de login, e quando terminasse todo o processo de autenticação, você realizasse um redirect forçado para a URL requisitada.

Comment: A questão é que não achei (ainda) uma forma de pegar essa URL que o usuário acessou e guardá-la até que a autenticação seja realizada.

Comment: Um `getRequestURL()` não resolve?